# Slow OpenGL context access on Ubuntu 12.4

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu, nvidia

I have an application which accesses OpenGL context.I run it on 2 OSs :

1.Kubuntu 13.4

2.Ubuntu 12.4

I am experiencing the following issue: on OS 1 it takes around 60 ms to setup the context, while on OS 2 it takes 10 times more.Both OSs use Nvidia GPUs with driver version 319.It also seems like OpenGL API calls are slower in general for OS 2.The contexts are offscreen.Currently I have no clue what could cause it.My question is what are possible sources of such an overhead?X11 setup?Or may be something on the OS level?

Another difference is that OS 1 uses Nvidia GTX680 while OS2 uses Nvidia GRID K1 card.Also OS2 resides on a server and the latency tests are run locally on that machine.

**UPDATE:**

This is the part which causes most of overhead:

```
typedef GLXContext (*glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)(Display*, GLXFBConfig, GLXContext, Bool, const int*);
typedef Bool (*glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc)(Display*, GLXDrawable, GLXDrawable, GLXContext);
static glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc glXCreateContextAttribsARB = 0;
static glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc glXMakeContextCurrentARB = 0;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    static int visual_attribs[] = {
            None
    };
    int context_attribs[] = {
            GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
            GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 0,
            None
    };

    Display* dpy = XOpenDisplay(0);
    int fbcount = 0;
    GLXFBConfig* fbc = NULL;
    GLXContext ctx;
    GLXPbuffer pbuf;

    /* open display */
    if ( ! (dpy = XOpenDisplay(0)) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open display\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    /* get framebuffer configs, any is usable (might want to add proper attribs) */
    if ( !(fbc = glXChooseFBConfig(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), visual_attribs, &fbcount) ) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get FBConfig\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    /* get the required extensions */
    glXCreateContextAttribsARB = (glXCreateContextAttribsARBProc)glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXCreateContextAttribsARB");
    glXMakeContextCurrentARB = (glXMakeContextCurrentARBProc)glXGetProcAddressARB( (const GLubyte *) "glXMakeContextCurrent");
    if ( !(glXCreateContextAttribsARB && glXMakeContextCurrentARB) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "missing support for GLX_ARB_create_context\n");
            XFree(fbc);
            exit(1);
    }

    /* create a context using glXCreateContextAttribsARB */
    if ( !( ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(dpy, fbc[0], 0, True, context_attribs)) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create opengl context\n");
            XFree(fbc);
            exit(1);
    }

    /* create temporary pbuffer */
    int pbuffer_attribs[] = {
            GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH, 800,
            GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT, 600,
            None
    };
    pbuf = glXCreatePbuffer(dpy, fbc[0], pbuffer_attribs);

    XFree(fbc);
    XSync(dpy, False);

    /* try to make it the current context */
    if ( !glXMakeContextCurrent(dpy, pbuf, pbuf, ctx) ){
            /* some drivers does not support context without default framebuffer, so fallback on
             * using the default window.
             */
            if ( !glXMakeContextCurrent(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), DefaultRootWindow(dpy), ctx) ){
                    fprintf(stderr, "failed to make current\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
    }

    /* try it out */
    printf("vendor: %s\n", (const char*)glGetString(GL_VENDOR));

    return 0;
}
```

Specifically , the line :

```
pbuf = glXCreatePbuffer(dpy, fbc[0], pbuffer_attribs);
```

where the dummy pbuffer is created is the slowest.If the rest of function calls take in average 2-4 ms,this call takes 40 ms on OS 1. Now , on OS2 (which is slow) the pbuffer creation takes 700ms! I hope now my problems looks more clear.

Comment: Why not show us the actually code? So that we can see why it's slow? As we don't magically know that, we need to see the code, the computer is running!

Comment: I don't see any change?

Comment: Btw,I hardly believe there is a problem with this code as it runs very fast on Kubuntu 13.4

Comment: And what's the problem with my question?

Comment: Dear people,if you can't answer the question then don't downvote it.I see no reason for it.The problem is well explained and a source code provided.

Comment: The reason why people download is... 1: There isn't any real problem, as you stated your program runs just fine! 2: You won't even supply your actual code, which is the most important thing, to be able to debunk why your code would be slow... and it's your code which is slow, so you can't just give us a link to some other random code and say... well that's kinda what my code is like. NO! supply YOUR code!

Comment: Added the source code.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure that this is necessarily something you are doing wrong. Although the general GPU architecture is the same/similar, these are two very different peripherals. GRID is effectively a GPGPU co-processor, it can be used for rendering but the path the output takes is very different (e.g. there is no RAMDAC that is constantly streaming the framebuffer to a display device). Context creation likely has to setup extra services/X modules behind the scenes to facilitate copying the output to some other device for display; whether it is 10x as much work I could not say.

Comment: The tech brief for NV's GRID solutions seems to indicate some more sophisticated technology than traditional pbuffer I/O to reduce latency, perhaps this accounts for the extra init. time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you *absolutely* sure "OS2" has correctly set up drivers and isn't falling back on SW OpenGL (Mesa) rendering?  What framerate does glxgears report on each system?

I note Ubuntu 12.4 was released April 2012 while I believe NVidia's "GRID" tech wasn't even announced until GTC May 2012 and I think cards didn't turn up until 2013 (see [relevant Nvidia press releases](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/search/default.aspx?SearchText=grid&NewsAreaId=2)).  Therefore it seems very unlikely Nvidia's drivers as supplied with Ubuntu 12.4 support the grid card (unless you've made some effort to upgrade using more recent driver releases from Nvidia?).

You may be able to check the list of supported hardware in `/usr/share/doc/nvidia-glx/README.txt.gz`'s Appendix A "Supported NVIDIA GPU Products" (at least that's where this useful information lives on my Debian machines).

Comment: Sure 100% as my OpenGL uses CORE 4.4 fully programmable profile.It would never run on Mesa or any SW rendering.

Comment: Interesting.  Which model card is it that you're calling the "GRID card"?  I was under the impression GRID was more a collection of visualisation technologies ( http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvidia-grid.html ) than "a card"; is your "OS2" actually also being accessed over the net in some remote VDI setup or something?

Comment: Yes,this is GRID K1(see the specs on nvidia).OS2 is on remote server but the latency test is done locally on that server.Now I am trying to understand if the difference in hardware (like CPU model) can cause it or maybe some processes running there block the pbuffer init...

Comment: Hmmm... who knows what overheads whatever magic Nvidia do to virtualize this stuff is imposing.  700ms sounds awfully long though; personally I'd be considering working up a minimial example and submitting a bug to NV.  I'd be a bit suspicious that even an offscreen pbuffer is triggering some over-the-net activity to your client though; can you monitor your connection with wireshark and see any activity on which ever port NV are using for their VDI?  How much latency to the server do you have?

Comment: \Another interesting detail is that running the same test on the same OS2 but with NVidia Tesla doesn't cause this overhead.